# Selecting all values and sum up a field's value from different table at the same time

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query, without the `,SUM(amount) AS total` it works fine. Now the problem is I want to select all the values from my table `vouchers` and at the same time want to get the sum value of the field `amount` from my another table called `details`.

```
SELECT *,SUM(amount) AS total FROM vouchers 
LEFT JOIN details on vouchers.voucher_no = details.voucher_no 
 LEFT JOIN   accounts on accounts.code = vouchers.account_code 
 WHERE (voucher_type='1' AND t_code=$code)
```

I tried the above query but it showed me the following error.(pls check the link)

http://i44.tinypic.com/bdaq.png

Comment: You cannot do aggregate operation without a GROUP BY clause...

Comment: You should prepend name of the table at the WHERE clause
    `WHERE (voucher.voucher_type='1' AND voucher.t_code=$code)`
and also avoid SQL-injection in `$code`

Answer (score 1):

Place the `details` sum into a subquery, against which you `LEFT JOIN`.  Your original was missing any `GROUP BY` clause for your `SUM()` aggregate.

```
SELECT
  vouchers.*,
  /* from the subquery... */
  detailssum.total
FROM
  vouchers
  LEFT JOIN (
    /* Subquery gets total per voucher_no to join against vouchers */
    SELECT voucher_no, t_code, SUM(amount) as total FROM details GROUP BY voucher_no
  ) detailssum ON vouchers.voucher_no = detailssum.voucher_no
  LEFT JOIN accounts on accounts.code = vouchers.account_code 
WHERE (voucher_type='1' AND t_code=$code)
```

(*We assume `$code` contains a sanitized and bounds-checked value already*)

Comment: Thanks Michael, for your reply. I have tried your code but still getting an error. Please check the link..http://i39.tinypic.com/2j1ofh1.png and yes $code contains a value that is already in my 'details' table.

Comment: @black_belt I assumed `t_code` was a column in `vouchers`. What table contains `t_code`? If it is in `details` then we'll need to modify the subquery a bit.

Comment: Thanks again. The table that contains "t_code" is details. Would you please kindly show me where to modify the subquery. Thanks again :)

Comment: @black_belt See above - `t_code` just needs to be added to the subquery SELECT list.